# How can the object parameter received by an input overloading function be const

Tags: c++, constants, operator-overloading, const-correctness

In class we're implementing vector, but I don't understand why the code for the input operator overloading is working:

```
istream& operator>> (istream& in, const Vector& A)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < A.size; i++)
        in >> A.data[i];
    return in;
}
```

I tried the code and it worked pretty well, but how can the vector reference be const even though we're inputting values for A?!

Comment: You did not show your actual class, but I'm assuming `data` is a pointer and the pointer itself is not `const`. As long as you don't modify the actual class members, the compiler will happily pass this. Whether that's _valid_ in terms of constness for your object is up to you. It's probably not, and this whole construction demonstrates a lack of proper data encapsulation.

Comment: @paddy — to clarify a bit, the pointer member would be `const` because the object that it’s a member of is `const`. If the type it points at hasn’t been marked `const` it can be modified even if the pointer itself is `const`. `const int*` points at a `const` object; `int*` points at a modifiable object. I completely agree that this shows a lack of proper data encapsulation.

Comment: For a case like this, you normally should not be using a reference to a const vector. Depending on how you've implemented your vector, you may well be able to get away with it, but it's clearly a poor idea, regardless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `Vector` contains some `T* data` pointer as a member, a `const Vector`'s member would be a `T* const` pointer. `T* const` is a `const` pointer to `T`, though `T` is mutable.

Therefore, `in >> A.data[i];` works, since it simply writes mutable data.

If you want constness to propagate deeply to the next pointer, you have to ensure this yourself:

```cpp
class Vector {
private:
    T* m_data;

public:
    T* data() {
        return m_data;
    }
    const T* data() const {
        return m_data;
    }
};
```

Now, `in >> A.data()[i]` would fail because `A.data()` would yield a pointer to `const T`.

This technique is used by containers like `std::vector`, see [`std::vector::data`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data).

### Note on language evolution

There is [`std::experimental::propagate_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const) which solves this without extra manual effort.

[P2670: Non-transient constexpr allocation](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2670r1.html) proposes a `propconst` specifier which would could be used as follows:

```cpp
struct Vector {
    // propagate const one level deep
    propconst(1) T* data;
};
```